# MS Excel Randomly pick name with freedom to choose how many to select

Tags: excel, vba

Everyone,

I'm trying to automated my excel file to choose random data to check for audit. I want to make randomizer that I can input how many data to select. is that possible in excel? I put some screenshot below for better explanation. I hope you can help me.

[image: Link for the Image]

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is absolutely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the usual excel functions this is indeed impossible...
However, excel (and the other Microsoft office applications) run an underlying programming language: visual basic. That's the way to go :)

Here's a makro, that selects a random field matching the search in the whole column.

```
Sub SelectRandomSearch()
    'Declaring Variables
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim startY As Integer
    Dim lastY As Integer
    Dim search As String
    Dim hits As Integer
    Dim random As Integer
    Dim hitsArr() As Integer
    Dim controlPart As Double
    Dim controlsNum As Integer
    Dim controlArr() As Integer

    'Declaring Values
    startY = 1        'lowest Y-Coordianate of the input column
    x = 1             'X-Coordiante of the input column
    controlPart = 0.1 'Fraction of the hits, that need to be controled

    'Get search value
    search = InputBox("Enter a search value", "Searching", "")

    'Getting Column Lenght and reset coloring
    y = startY
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(y, x).Value)
        Cells(y, x).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        y = y + 1
    Loop

    'Getting number of search hits
    lastY = y - 1
    hits = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(startY, x), Cells(lastY, x)), search)

    'Fill hitsArr with row-numbers of hits
    ReDim hitsArr(hits + 1)
    hits = 1
    For y = startY To lastY
        If Cells(y, x) = search Then
            hitsArr(hits) = y
            hits = hits + 1
        End If
    Next y
    hits = hits - 1

    'Getting number of controlled Entries
    controlsNum = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(hits * controlPart, 0)

    'Shuffle a part of hitsArr
    ReDim controlArr(controlsNum + 1)
    For y = 1 To controlsNum
        random = ((hits - y + 1) * Rnd + y)
        hitsArr(0) = hitsArr(y)
        hitsArr(y) = hitsArr(random)
        hitsArr(random) = hitsArr(0)
    Next y

    'Mark every hit that needs to be controlled
    For y = 1 To controlsNum
        Cells(hitsArr(y), x).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Color = 49407
        End With
    Next y
End Sub
```

You probably need to change the makro slightly, but this basicly does all I can think of you could need :)

I hope this helps!

Now the makro marks the fields that need to be checkt like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Anton. Do you think you can make just the first part. selecting or list the name of the chosen from random. like in the picture from 8 choose 1?

Comment: I think I can do that ^^ my vb is a bit rusty, but expect it to be done soon :)

Comment: Very much appreciate. Thank you Anton. this is a big help for me.

Comment: Hi Anton. Thank you for your time. but I'm afraid that this is only works by choosing 1. what if the Apple is now 100 so i need to get that 10% which is 10. i need to select 10 random names. this is cause to much edit on the macro. but anyway thank you for the help :D .

Comment: @P.Alvs So you basicly want an array with a set amount of random entries? I could do that ^^

Comment: No Problem ^^ Just give me a bit more time :P

Comment: Thank you Anton very much appreciate.

Comment: You'll have to wait a little longer, since working with arrays in vba is a real pain...

Comment: Its Okay Anton I'll wait. I'm always visit this waiting for your reply :D.

Comment: Hi Anton Thank you very much i will try this and let you know.

Comment: Do that... Also you should probably close the topic so that others don't think a working answer is still missing...

Comment: Hi. Anton. Yes It's totally working just fine thank you. but May I ask some of changes if possible. 1. rather than listing the pick number in the next column is that possible to just highlighted it to easily filter?. 2. good thing that its already getting the total amount of how many should i audit but i think its not getting the 10% of it. showing that it getting the 1/3 of the total number of search. other than this everything works fine. thank you.

Comment: 1. I'll try to do that, it should be doable...
2. You can customize the amount with the variables at the top... In my example it's at 0.3, but you can simply change it to 0.1

Comment: Thank you so much Anton.

Comment: Sooooo... I REALLY think this is all you should need ^^

Comment: Wow this is what i wanted. thank you so much Anton. this is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: @P.Alvs Seems like that's it than ^^ Whenever you have a new question feel free to ask me :P

Comment: Yeah I will do that :D .. actually I already have 1 question but this is too much so its ok if this is impossible to make. the "search" thing. im wondering if theres like a command that show a popup box that i will just enter the name and automatically change search so i will not go to vba to manually change search "Apple". But anyway this is perfect thank you.

Comment: Well, that's easy ^^

Comment: Hi. Anton. I am using the Macro you made and it help me a lot. but now i realize that the popup box is not a great idea. can you help me make some changes with it? rather than typing the name to search in box, whenever i click the macro it will randomize and get the Apple and Banana highlighted so i just need to click once. sorry for my bad english.